# No longer possible to index a pandas DatetimeIndex with a date?

Tags: pandas, date, datetimeindex

I've just upgraded to pandas 1.1 from 0.24 and I feel like I have lost my mind. Is it true that you can no longer index a DatetimeIndex with, you know, a date?

```
#This now fails!
import datetime as dt
s = pd.Series([1,2], pd.DatetimeIndex([dt.date(2020,1,1),dt.date(2020,1,2)]))
s.loc[dt.date(2020,1,2)]
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-18ac6239cd3a> in <module>
      1 s = pd.Series([1,2], pd.DatetimeIndex([dt.date(2020,1,1),dt.date(2020,1,2)]))
----> 2 s.loc[dt.date(2020,1,2)]
....
```

Please tell me I'm wrong!

Comment: What is `dt`? I assume it's `import datetime as dt` but if I do that, your code works for me

Comment: What version of pandas pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug that's going to be fixed in 1.1.1

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35466